# I don't know what's the problem in my code

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm learning basic kotlin in these days.

```kotlin
class Human (val name : String = "Anonymous") {
    fun drinkingCoffee() {
        println("this is so good")
    }
}
```

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var human = Human(name: "jinhwa") // error is here.
    human.drinkingCoffee()
    println("this is human's name is ${human.name}") 
}
```

android studio said Expecting ')', but I can't find out why this isn't work

Answer (score 3):

So basically you messed up with a colon while calling `Human()`. A colon is used to specify type like `var x: String = ""` when you're using named arguments you do `name = value`

Reference: [kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#named-arguments), [kotlin by example](https://play.kotlinlang.org/byExample/08_productivity_boosters/01_namedArguments)

Full code:

```
class Human(val name: String = "Anonymous") {

    fun drinkingCoffee() {
        println("this is so good")
    }

}

fun main() {
    var human = Human(name = "jinhwa") // error is here.
    human.drinkingCoffee()

    println("this is human's name is ${human.name}")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is an invalid part of the argument to the constructor of your `class Human`.

## tl;dr

**This is wrong:** `Human(name : "jinhwa")`
**This is correct:** `Human(name = "jinhwa")`

You don't have to give the name of a specific argument when calling the constructor, especially when there is only a single one, but you can do it.
**If you do it, write an equality sign where you have written a colon in your code.**

Valid constructor calls in your scenario are

- a call without passing a parameter: `Human()`
- a call with a parameter value but no parameter name: `Human("jinhwa")`
- a call with a parameter name and value: `Human(name = "jinhwa")`

So the following code that uses your `class Human`...

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var defaultConstructedHuman = Human()
    var withparamNameConstructedHuman = Human(name = "jinhwa")
    var withoutParamNameConstructedHuman = Human("Arthur")
    
    println("this human's name is ${defaultConstructedHuman.name}") 
    println("this human's name is ${withparamNameConstructedHuman.name}") 
    println("this human's name is ${withoutParamNameConstructedHuman.name}") 
}
```

and the code will run.

It will also run if you create a `Human` without passing a name, the result would be an `Anonymous` one:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var human = Human() // nothing passed, "name" takes the default value "Anonymous"
    human.drinkingCoffee()
    println("this is human's name is ${human.name}") 
}
```

... will compile and output

```
this human's name is Anonymous
this human's name is jinhwa
this human's name is Arthur
```